# Apex trigger for feed items

Tags: apex, trigger

How can I create trigger to create feed items for the followers of case contact if a new case is created
I have done it so far but its not working.

```
trigger CreateCaseFeedOnFollowers on Case (before insert) {
     list<FeedItem> lst=new List<feedItem>();
     for(Case c:trigger.new){
        FeedItem fi= new FeedItem();
        set<Id> conIdList = new Set<Id>();
        map<Id,Id> followMap = new Map<Id,Id>(); 

        conIdList.add(c.Contact.Id); 

        List<EntitySubscription> followers = [select id, subscriberid, subscriber.name from EntitySubscription where parentid In :conIdList ];
        for(EntitySubscription ent : followers){
            followMap.put(ent.ParentId , ent.id);
        }

            fi.parentId = followMap.get(c.Contact.Id); 
            fi.body='Modified the Content';
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user10055, did you already try something or did some research into the datamodel ? It's unclear what part of writing that trigger is actually stopping you from progressing, or isn't clear to you.

Comment: My trigger has been saved but its not creating feed items on followers page

Comment: If you edit the code into your question, we could have a look at what might be going wrong. Using the {} button in the editor, you can format your code.

Comment: Im not entirely familiar with the chatter datamodel, so haven't looked if that may be incorrect. But: you aren't inserting your feedItem into the database !  And, this may make more sense as an after-insert trigger so that you are sure your case has been inserted.

Comment: So when someone creates a Case, EntitySubscription gets updated?